Фиксирование параметров функции для curve_fit
Существуют ли удобные способы фиксировать один или несколько параметров уравнения в функции curve_fit()?
У меня есть некоторая гипотетическая функция myFunc. Стандартный способ получения её параметров отлично работает:
def myFunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x**2 + b * x + c

[a, b, c], _ = curve_fit(myFunc, xdata, ydata)

Но что делать, если один или несколько параметров я уже получил и хочу использовать их как константы при новом curve_fit с новыми данными.
Например, я уже знаю a и c и мне нужен вывод
def myFunc(x, c):
    a = 1
    c = 2
    return a * x**2 + b * x + c

[b], _ = curve_fit(myFunc, xdata, ydata)

Можно использовать разные функции. Даже удобно и быстро их задавать лямбда функциями, как предложили тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208634/fitting-only-one-parameter-of-a-function-with-many-parameters-in-python
Но для n параметров надо будет написать 2^n условий и функций, что не является оптимальным решением.

не совсем понятен вопрос: вам нужно получить из функции curve_fit только какой-то один параметр из, например, четырёх?

Лямбда выглядит удобно. Если у вас много вариантов наборов параметров наверное можно как-то **kwargs туда припахать, но нужно какие-то более конкретные примеры привести что вы хотите сделать.
